# Redirecting from other pages in js

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-extension, redirect

How would one redirect a user from a site like youtube back to another url in js? This would be done through a chrome extension. The purpose would be to keep you focused, and redirect you from distracting sites.

Answer (score -1):

The most popular chrome/firefox extension these days and quite simple one is Requestly.
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/requestly/mdnleldcmiljblolnjhpnblkcekpdkpa?hl=en

For details, please have a look at http://www.requestly.in/.

You can easily create a Redirect Rule based on exact match or regular expressions.